# Retrieve some data from a currently playing video file on windows?

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, vlc

I'd like to get the current time of a playing video and then read from a relevant subtitle file and stream the subtitles at the right time to a terminal-like window. Getting the subtitles directly from the video file would probably be more efficient, but I'd like to tackle one problem at a time.

What's the best way to do this?

I've looked at VLC's modules and such, but it seems I'd have to completely recompile it with my module for each targeted platform. Which I'd rather just have a standalone project in C++.

I've tried reversing through cheat engine so I could ReadProcessMemory(). but can't seem to find anything related to current time. Tried VLC and Windows Media Player.